# How make Google Play Store like view in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where I display some resources that have been uploaded by some admin users in the form of a google play store view.

It looks like something below:
[image]

I need to make a CSS view of this resource and then repopulate the same view for all the resources.

This is what I have implemented till now:

a.img-list {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

```
    ul.img-list li {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 150px;
    }

    .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    span.text-content span {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    span.text-content {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: table;
        height: 150px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 150px;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
        -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
        -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
        transition: opacity 500ms;
    }

    ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

for displaying my resources.

Comment: You want css and html for this box design. right?

Comment: https://material.google.com

Comment: Yes, CSS for the box design.

Comment: Do you have any code of your website.

Comment: can you send you website or demo url.

Comment: I don't see the need for the code. Every resource has a preview, resource title, description, rating, author name and price.

Comment: You can assume them as static values for the purpose of this question and design the CSS around it.

Comment: Can any of the downvoters explain your reasoning behind downvoting this question.

Comment: because you haven't even tried to do something: no HTML structure, no css code. You expect that someone do the work.

Comment: I assumed that google play store uses a very standard and structured way of representing its resources and someone would have created it already. I didn't ask anyone to write it out for me, I just asked if someone could provide the css behind this since this is standard. Moreover, it's not like I didn't try implementing something on my own, here is what I have implemented.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```css
.box{width: 180px;background: #fff;box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);margin: 10px;font-family: Arial,sans-serif;}
.box img{width: 100%;}
.box .content{padding: 10px;}
.box p{margin: 7px 0;}
.box .title{color: #333;font-size: 18px;}
.box .price{color: #ed3b3b;float:right;}
.box .author{font-size: 16px;}
.box .desc{font-style: italic;font-size: 14px;color: #616161;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/apDLpFcXDG-Pal2n8_xhWoKm21OrDT0ib2d-R4rMQVLC6VtojnkYcfibE-JKlZoVisIh=w170-rw">
  <div class="content">
    <p class="title">
    The time machine
    </p>
    <p>
      <span class="author">H.G Wells</span>
      <span class="price">$226.80</span>
    </p>
    <p class="desc">
  Popular with time machine readers
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/tsebautr/